# AppData folder under the virtual directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I created a web application in asp.net with sql server 2008 .I made a web setup project.Deployed into the server(IIS) with the msi i created.So for some reason a folder named "appdata" is getting created where the the application is deployed.
I even deleted the folder in my code and built again the msi.But still the folder is getting created.

Earlier i used the aspnet.mdf to create users but i am no longer using it as i am using a sql table.But still i am unable to know where my fault is .. Does it have some thing to do with my web.config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the App_Data folder isn't excluded from your project. If it is excluded, delete it from the project entirely and republish.

If that doesn't work:

Under the Publish dialog, make sure that the "Include files from the App_Data folder" checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: i exactly did the same thing deleting the App_Data folder from the project but for some reason its getting recreated.

Comment: I am not publishing it directly i am making a setup project which gives me an msi ..i am deploying it in other server where the database exists ..